# How to change toolbar text color from MaterialComponents.DayNight theme?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-styles, material-components, material-components-android

I am using MaterialComponents.DayNight theme in my app. In the day mode, toolbar text color is black. But when I switch to night mode toolbar text color is remain black, so it's not visible anymore.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
```

I want to change the toolbar text color into white in night mode. How can I do that?

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?

Comment: @androiddeveloper I've posted an answer below

Comment: Ok thank you. Here, get +1 from me :)

Answer (score 24):

Just use in your Layout (it works also with the `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`) the style:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary"
```

Then define in the `values-night/colors.xml` the **`colorOnPrimary`**.

Then there are a lot of alternatives.
You can customize globally the style of the toolbar in the app theme with:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
  <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/MyToolbar</item>
</style>
```

with:

```
  <style name="MyToolbar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
    <item name="titleTextColor">@color/.....</item>
  </style>
```

and the define the color in the `values/colors.xml` and `values-night/colors.xml`.

Or just apply a style in the Toolbar

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
    style="@style/MyToolbar"
```

or simply override the theme with:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
   android:theme="@style/MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar"
```

with:

```
  <style name="MyThemeOverlay_Toolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Primary">
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/...</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: The corret is that... thanks man

Answer (score 7):

Set your parent theme to `parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar.Bridge"`

By using this, you will keep your ActionBar's original theme with DarkActionBar attributes on top of the overal DayNight theme from MaterialComponents.

Answer (score 6):

Add this entry to your theme:

```
<item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/PopupMenuTextAppearance</item>
```

After that, add the style accordingly to the `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="PopupMenuTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Menu">
    <item name="android:textColor">?attr/colorOnBackground</item>
</style>
```

`?attr/colorOnBackground` is available in the [Material Components library](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/). If you're not using that, you should be able to use `?android:attr/textColorPrimary` instead.

Answer (score 2):

in my opinion you should set the style on noActionbar and design new toolbar and customize it

Answer (score 1):

I used these two lines of code inside the styles.xml file:

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
```

It changed the color on the toolbar text and the toolbar X icon to white.

The whole code looked like this:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#00695c</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">#439889</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">#007769</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">#48a697</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```