# Overriding Style XML for Component

Tags: android

im using Material IO and i want to Change the Text-Color of my Menu.

```
<resources>
...
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
        ...
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorText</item>
    </style>
...
<resources>
```

Does exactly that. But it changes every Text Color. But i just want to Change the Color of my Menu-Text.

So i tried to change only that:

```html
<style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorMenuText</item> //android.view
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorMenuText</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="popupTheme">@style/ActionBarPopupTheme</item>
            <!-- backward compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

by writing some Thing like This.
I can change the Menu-Background this way, but i cant change the Menu-Text-Color this way. I tried everything i found on Stackoverflow but i couldnt fix this issue.

Whole Styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorMenuText</item> //android.view
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorMenuText</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@color/colorWhite</item>

        <item name="android:background">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="popupTheme">@style/ActionBarPopupTheme</item>
        <!-- backward compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:colorAccent">#0000FF</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarPopupTheme">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorMenuText</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorMenuBackground</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
        <!-- MENU -->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>

        <!-- DIALOG -->
        <item name="md_color_title">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="md_color_content">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="md_color_button_text">@color/colorAccent</item>


        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorTest2</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorTest3</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/colorMenuText</item>

        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
        <item name="color">@color/colorTest4</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">#FF0000</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorBackground</item>
        <item name="colorError">@color/colorError</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/colorTest</item>
        <item name="colorSurface">#313131</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">#00BCD4</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">#00BCD4</item>
        <item name="colorOnBackground">#673AB7</item>
        <item name="colorOnError">#2196F3</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/colorOnAccent</item> <!-- placeholder farbe -->
        <item name="scrimBackground">#E607FF</item>


        <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/colorText</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorText</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorText</item>
        <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/colorText</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/colorText</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@color/colorText</item>
        <item name="android:textColorTertiaryInverse">@color/colorText</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorMenuText</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <!-- DIALOG -->
        <item name="md_color_title">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="md_color_content">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="md_color_button_text">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <!-- Original AppCompat attributes. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorTest4</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorTest5</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorBackground</item>
        <item name="colorError">@color/colorError</item>

        <!-- New MaterialComponents attributes. -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/colorTest</item>
        <item name="colorSurface">#313131</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">#9C27B0</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">#00BCD4</item>
        <item name="colorOnBackground">#673AB7</item>
        <item name="colorOnError">#2196F3</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurface">#E91E63</item>
        <item name="scrimBackground">#FFC107</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceHeadline1">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline1</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceHeadline2">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline2</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceHeadline3">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline3</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceHeadline4">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline4</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceHeadline5">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline5</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceHeadline6">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceSubtitle1">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceSubtitle2">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle2</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceBody1">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceBody2">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceCaption">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceButton">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Button</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceOverline">@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Overline</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: do you need to change text color for option menu items only?

Comment: @MohammedAlaa i want to change them and the text color of the menu title,  but i dont want it to affect the rest of the views

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54613443/how-to-change-toolbar-text-color-from-materialcomponents-daynight-theme)

Comment: @MohammedAlaa already done everything they suggested there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this minimum sample of your code and it gives me the desired behavior
I think there is a conflict with your styles

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffffff</item>//for title text color
    <item name="colorPrimary">#D81B60</item>// for toolbar background
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ActionBarPopupTheme</item>

</style>

<style name="ActionBarPopupTheme">
    <item name="android:textColor">#304FFE</item> // for option menu text color
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: just to be on the same page, i want to change the color of the test on the left side

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/qW1hzbL.png i want to change teh ad hoc database - text color

Comment: sadly didnt work, but now my background is #Coloraccent aswell :D

Comment: android:background inside ActionBarTheme did that - so i removed that, but the title is still black

Comment: I'm sorry to here that , as the updated image , I changed the test text-color to white

Comment: ok now id worked, -> https://i.imgur.com/uDJBn1x.png  thank you!

Comment: I think , it's related to the new activity which have this controls , try to make this activity theme extend from the AppTheme